How Do I select Item in list with LegacyIAccessibleChildId?
How do I modify this code to use UIA_LegacyIAccessibleChildIdPropertyId instead of UIA_NamePropertyId?
This code is written in Excel VBA and used To Control my design Software Catia.
I have simplified my working code down to show my question, but I want to replace "DET-0060" with "8".
I have used Windows Inspect to see the items in the list have ChildIds.
Dim winAutomation As CUIAutomation
Set winAutomation = New CUIAutomation

Dim graphWin As IUIAutomationElement

Set graphWinCond = winAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Reorder Children")

Dim graphWin As IUIAutomationElement

Dim btnProdCondition As IUIAutomationCondition
Dim btnProd As IUIAutomationElement
Dim selectPart As IUIAutomationInvokePattern

Set btnProdCondition = winAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "DET-0060")
Set btnProd = graphWin.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, btnProdCondition)
Set selectPart = btnProd.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
selectPart.Invoke

